# Matlab: getting figure handles into subplots

Tags: matlab, parent, children, matlab-figure, subplot

I have two figures with figure handles `h1` and `h2`. I'd like to use them as subplots in a single figure and run

```
figure
s1=subplot(211);
s2=subplot(212);
hc1=get(h1, 'children');
hcc1=get(hc1, 'children');
hc2=get(h2, 'children');
hcc2=get(hc2, 'children');
set(hcc1,'parent',s1);
set(hcc2,'parent',s2);
```

This works well for the first figure but not the second (`h2`), where I get the error

```
Error using set
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.
```

The two figures are the same except for details, so I don't understand why. I tried using `set(hc2,'parent',s2);`, i.e. "one less parent," and also one more, i.e. `hccc2=get(hcc2, 'children'); set(hcc2,'parent',s2);`, with the same errors. Can anyone see what's going on?

Comment: What type of handle are you trying to get from those `get` statements? axes? line? Also, why not just create them in the subplot in the first  place?

Comment: The handles originally come from `h1=figure` etc, and as mentioned it works for the first one. Yeah I'm considering altering the original code as you suggest but it's a pretty big job (the original plays a "movie" and I want to take a few "screenshots" of that as subplots).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a specific type of object's handle, try using [`findobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) to look for a specific `'Type'` property.  For example,

```
ha1 = findobj(h1,'Type','axes');
```

However, you can probably just apply [`copyobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) (instead of changing the `'parent'`:

```
copyobj(ha1,hf2)
```

This way you can copy the axes (`ha1`) to a new figure (`hf2`). You can do the same with any graphics element, like copying a plot (`'Type'` of `'line'`) to a new axes.